# How can we count the number of check boxes checked inside a grid view in asp.net using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I asked this question in an interview. In asp.net how can we check the no. of checked boxes using javascript.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using jquery you can get the number of checkboxes on a html page by this

```
alert($('input:checkbox').length);
```

Or by using the following jquery code to determine the complete picture

```
var totalNoOfChkBoxes = 0;
var NoOfCheckedchkBoxes = 0;
var NoOfUnCheckedChkBoxes = 0;
$('input:checkbox').each(function () {
  if ($(this).is(':checkbox')) {
    totalNoOfChkBoxes += 1;
    if($(this).attr('value') == "on")
      NoOfCheckedchkBoxes += 1;
    else
      NoOfUnCheckedChkBoxes += 1;
   }
});
alert(totalNoOfChkBoxes);
alert(NoOfCheckedchkBoxes);
alert(NoOfUnCheckedChkBoxes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($('input:checked[type=checkbox]').length);
```

This will display number of checked checkboxes in a page.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
var cbs = []; //will contain all checkboxes   
var checked = []; //will contain all checked checkboxes  
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {     
     if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {  
         cbs.push(inputs[i]);  
         if (inputs[i].checked) {  
             checked.push(inputs[i]);  
         }     
     }  
}   
var nbCbs = cbs.length; //number of checkboxes   
var nbChecked = checked.length; //number of checked checkboxes
```